# How to code a slider that can change the radius of an object

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm trying to figure out how to code a slider that will change the radius of a certain shapes. The assignment will output as an HTML webdoc and many of the ways ive tried to solve this problem end up causing the webdoc to output as a blank page. I have created a slider in my HTML file inside a table element, and created subsequent code in my javascript file. I looked up one tutorial that suggested using object.setRadius, to change the radius. It was for a java file so that could explain why it didn't work. I've tried multiple ways and everything seems to allow the slider to move, but nothing seems to ever effect the shapes. What am I doing wrong?

```
threeComponents2.js
"use strict";



let vertex_shader  = `
    attribute  vec4 vPosition;
    attribute  vec4 vColor;
    varying vec4 fcolor;


    void main()
    {
        gl_PointSize = 10.0;
        gl_Position = vPosition;       
        fcolor = vColor;
}
`;

let fragment_shader = `
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec4 fcolor;

    void
        main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = fcolor;
    }
`;




let lg;

window.addEventListener("load", function init() {

    lg = noLogging();
    lg.insertAtEnd = false;


    const canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    const gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    const program = initShaders( gl, vertex_shader, fragment_shader);
    gl.useProgram( program );


    let node1 = new cs4722_objects.Node(new cs4722_objects.Cylinder(10));
    node1.object.center = [.27,.25,.25,1];
    node1.object.radius_top = .4;
    node1.object.radius_bottom = .25;
    node1.object.height = .5;

    let node2 = new cs4722_objects.Node(new cs4722_objects.Sphere());
    node2.object.center = [-.25,-.25,-.25,1];
    node2.object.radius = .25;
    node2.object.scheme_colors = [X11.SkyBlue3, X11.Gold2];

    let node3 = new cs4722_objects.Node(new cs4722_objects.Block());
    node3.object.center = [-.4, .25, 0, 1];
    node3.object.height = .5;
    node3.object.width = .5;
    node3.object.scheme_colors = [X11.SkyBlue1, X11.SkyBlue2, X11.SkyBlue3, X11.Purple1, X11.Purple2, X11.Purple3];


    let node0 = new cs4722_objects.Node();
    node0.children.push(node2);
    node0.children.push(node1);
    node0.children.push(node3);


    let scene = new cs4722_objects.Scene(node0);
    scene.load_vertices(gl, program);
    scene.load_colors(gl, program);

    const csc = cs4722_controls;

    function render() {
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        scene.draw(gl);
    }


    var sphereSlider = document.getElementById("radius");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");


// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    sphereSlider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
        node2.setRadius(this.value);
    }

   /* csc.addCheckbox("controls", "sphere-vis", "Sphere Visible",
        node2.visible,
        (event) => {
            node2.visible = event.target.checked;
        },
        render);

    csc.addCheckbox("controls", "cylinder-vis", "Cylinder Visible",
        node1.visible,
        (event) => {
            node1.visible = event.target.checked;
        },
        render);

    csc.addCheckbox("controls", "block-vis", "Block Visible",
        node3.visible,
        (event) => {
            node3.visible = event.target.checked;
        },
        render);*/

    render();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I read through your code but I don't see where your slider returns a variable you can use to change the size of your shapes.  What is node2.setRadius actually calling?

Comment: so node2 is my circle object and node2.setRadius should should call the valuse to be set by the slider.

Answer (score 0):

try look at this it might help you some

https://codepen.io/codedevlo/pen/BOOOaQ

I think it is something like this

```
var slider;
ellipse(200, 200, slider);    
document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = slider;
```

and the HTML

```
<input type="range" min="40" max="400" value="40" class="slider">
```

i think that should work

Comment: or a little like that any way